# Change border length from textbox with CSS3?

Tags: css

I'm with some free time and I wanted to do some of the design from Android 4.0 in a demo web. I am stuck with these textboxes:

[image: http://developer.android.com/design/static/content/text_input_typesandtypedown.png]

Is there some way to limit those left and right borders length with CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But the effect is very easy to recreate using pseudo elements.

```
div {position:relative; border-bottom:5px solid black;;}
div:after,div:before{content:''; width:5px; height:20px; background:black; 
position:absolute; bottom:-5px;}
div:after{right:-5px;}
div:before{left:-5px;}
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1608599)

Comment: Fantastic, I modified some numbers and it's working great, thank you.